# Output HTTP responses with Jersey Test Framework?

Tags: unit-testing, jersey, integration-testing

Can the Jersey Test Framework be configured to output the raw HTTP responses when a test case fails?  I'd like to be able to see the detailed error information returned by the server.

Answer (score 5):

You can enable HTTP logging like so

```
public class SimpleTest extends JerseyTest {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        // ...
    }
}
```

More details [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#d0e12030).

This is for the latest version of the framework, currently 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can always enable the normal Jersey logging for Request and Responses and see what is shows in the console:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter<</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Enable logging programmatically:

```
servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters"    , "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter");
servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters"  , "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter");
```